# Power BI Integration with Spring Angular

Tags: angular, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, powerbi

i'm currently developing a web application using Spring/Angular.

I need to integrate Power Bi in my application to be able to create datasets and reports with Spring and get the charts in Angular.

Is there any examples or tutorials to help me get started ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to know that there are two modes for embedding Power BI - `user owns data` and `app owns data`. With the first mode, when embedding, the user will authenticate itself using it's own Power BI Pro account, i.e. each of your users needs Power BI Pro license. With the later one, you need only one "master account", which will be used for authentication. The differences in the implementation aren't tremendous, so I will describe `app owns data`.

You need to do the following:

- Register an application - go to [dev.powerbi.com/apps](https://dev.powerbi.com/apps) and register a native application. Select which permissions to grant it (if you aren't sure, for your first tests simply grant them all). Copy the guid - this is the app ID, a.k.a. client ID.
- Next step is to authenticate from your application and get an access token. Use [Azure Active Directory Authentication Library (ADAL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-libraries) for that - call some of the `acquireToken` methods of `AuthenticationContext` class.
- Use this access token to call the Power BI REST API and get the `embedUrl` of the element you want to embed, e.g. [report](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/getreportingroup#report).
- Use [Power BI JavaScript client](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Embedding-Basics) to actually embed this element. You need to initialize one [embed configuration class](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Embed-Configuration-Details) and pass information about element type (report, dashboard, tile), where to find it (embedUrl), authentication (access token), some other configuration options (show or hide filters pane, navigation, etc.), filters to be applied and so on. In case you will use the access token acquired above, set `tokenType` to be `AAD`. This token has many privileges, so for security reasons you may want to use `Embed` token instead. In this case use the access token to call the REST API again (e.g. [Reports GenerateTokenInGroup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/embedtoken/reports_generatetokeningroup)).
- Call `powerbi.embed` method of the JavaScript client pass the embedded configuration to visualize this Power BI element in your app.

Here are some resources, that you should read:

- [Tutorial: Embed Power BI content into an application for your customers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-sample-for-customers)
- [Tutorial: Embed Power BI content into an application for your organization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-sample-for-your-organization)
- [Embedding Basics](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Embedding-Basics)
- [Power BI Embedded Playground](https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/demo/v2-demo/index.html)
- [PowerBI Developer Samples](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples)

Comment: Thank you , great explanation very clear. One Question : Do I need Pro License only to use it ??

Comment: I never tried, because I heavily use workspaces and they are Pro feature. But if you publish the report in My Workspace, and use your own credentials for the master account in app owns data scenario, it may work. Just try it.

Comment: Thank you very much , i will try it.