# View Power BI embed report without authenticating

Tags: powerbi

I have an angular application in which i have some power BI reports using the iframe generated from the embed report method.

I just want the user of the applcation to see the report without autheticating with a microsoft BI account

Thanks for the help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Power BI Integration with Spring Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60838217/power-bi-integration-with-spring-angular)

Comment: @AndreyNikolov Thanks i will try it and tell you